# Vuejs, I am trying to do a push of a subobject to an array

Tags: arrays, vuejs2, push, vuetify.js

I am starting in the programming, I am trying to do a push of a subobject to an array and that it is shown for example 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 etc.
They are clauses with subclauses, here I leave a codepen with what I already have. Any help or advice is well received. Thank you

https://codepen.io/ivanmercado9/pen/GGGJpg?editors=1010

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-content class="pa-5">
      <v-card flat class="grey lighten-2 ma-3 pa-3">
                    <v-card-text>
            <v-layout row wrap> 
              <v-flex xs10 offset-xs1>
                <v-card dark color="deep-purple darken-1">
                  <v-card-text> 
                    <div v-for="(item, index) in clauses">


                      <p>Clause {{1+index}}</p>
                      <v-text-field label="Clause" textarea v-model="item.description"></v-text-field>


                      <!--      Sub Clause            -->
                      <div v-for="(item, index) in clauses.subclauses">
                        <p>Sub Clause {{1+index}}</p>
                        <v-text-field label="Clause" textarea v-model="item.description"></v-text-field>
                      </div>


                      <v-btn dark color="light-green" @click="addSubClause(i)">Add Sub Clause</v-btn> 
                      <div v-if="clauses.length > 1">
                          <v-btn dark color="red" @click="deleteElement(index)">Delete Clause</v-btn>

                      </div>

                    </div>
                    <v-btn dark color="light-green" @click="addClause()">Add Clause</v-btn>
                  </v-card-text>
                </v-card>
              </v-flex>  
            </v-layout>
          </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
      <v-divider></v-divider>

      <v-card flat class="grey lighten-2 ma-3 pa-3">
                    <v-card-text>
           Clauses: {{ clauses }}
          </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
      <v-card flat class="grey lighten-2 ma-3 pa-3">
                    <v-card-text>
            <div v-for="(item, index) in clauses">
              <p><span>{{1+index}}.</span><span> {{item.description}}</span></p>
            </div>
          </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    //
    clauses: [],
  }),
  methods: {
    addClause: function () {
      this.clauses.push({
        description: '',
      })
    },
    addSubClause: function (i) {
      this.clauses[i].subclauses.push({
        description: '',
      })
    },
    deleteElement: function(val) {
              this.clauses.splice(val, 1)
      },

  },
  created() {
    // this.addClause()
  },
})
```

Comment: Eh... what is the question? Is your code malfunctioning in any way? What would you expect? What is happening instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues.

First, the `i` your `@click` on the "Add Sub Clause" button is not a dynamic argument — it isn't indicating an index, it is `undefined`. You'll need a mechanism/variable to cache/reference the clause that each "Add Sub Clause" button refers to. **EDIT**: It looks like `index` would refer to the Clause in question.

```
<v-btn dark color="light-green" @click="addSubClause(index)">Add Sub Clause</v-btn>
```

Next, once you're passing a legitimate index, you won't be able to use methods of the [Array prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) — `.push()` in this case — on a new property of `this.clauses[i]` unless you declare it to be an array. You could do that when you create each Clause instance:

```
addClause: function () {
    this.clauses.push({
        description: '',
        subclauses: []
    })
},
```